# How to get current state value in function component?

Tags: reactjs, state, render, react-component

I am trying to get the same number (input and div) in Function Component when clicking on a button, is it possible?

```
function App() {

 let [someState, setSomeState] = useState(5)
 let [otherSomeState, setOtherSomeState] = useState(7)

 let stateChanger = () => {
   setSomeState(otherSomeState + someState)
   setOtherSomeState(someState)
 }

 return (
   <div className="App">
     <div>{someState}</div>
     <input value={otherSomeState} onChange={ ()=>false }  />
     <button onClick={ ()=>stateChanger() }>Add</button>
   </div>
 );
}
```

As I understand it, I need to call the component's render again, but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: You don't trigger the re-render, that's React's job. `someState` is the current state, I think what you're trying to access is the *next* state, or what the state *will* be. To do that, just use the same method as when you set it: `setOtherSomeState(otherSomeState + someState)` **or** set the "other" state in a `useEffect` that depends on `someState`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. If you need to display the same state inside two elements, just use the specific state variable you need, and React will take care of the rest. No need to trigger re-renders.